# Get a row of images to slide horizontally when clicked using AngularJS and CSS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have an unordered list of images, with only 3 being shown at a time, how can use animations to achieve a horizontal scrolling effect? I'd rather not use jQuery or other 3rd party plugins if possible

Comment: You have a lot of options here, but since you're not using a library I would probably use CC3 transitions. This is a good article to get started with http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/